# Using typeof within a for-in loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof, for-in-loop

I have created an object with 6 properties out of which first 3 properties are of string data type and the second 3 are of number data type. I decided to print the values of the properties of string data type alone. But my code is printing the values of all the properties available. The following is my code. Someone help me correct it.

```
var family = {
    dad: "Two",
    mom: "Twenty Two",
    kid: "Thirty Two",
    dadAge: 42,
    momAge: 41,
    kidAge: 12,

};

for(prop in family){
    if(typeof prop === "string"){
        console.log(family[prop]);
    }
}
```

Comment: its if(typeof family[prop] === "string").. check my answer.. Prop only gives they the key not value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be      `if(typeof family[prop] === "string")`

```
for(prop in family){
    if(typeof family[prop] === "string"){
        console.log(family[prop]);
    }
}
```

`prop` represents the key and its always "`string`" whereas you need to use `family[prop]` which will return you the value you have stored in the object

Answer (score 1):

`prop` will always be a string, since it contains the name of the property. You can do this:

```
for(prop in family){
    if(typeof family[prop] === "string"){
        console.log(family[prop]);
    }
}
```